# Bootstrap fullscreen google maps with navbar

Tags: html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full screen google map application with a navbar on the top.

So i have a setup like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <nav bar stuff......>
</div>
<div id="mapcanvas"></div>
```

with the mapcanvas element having height and width to be 100%.

However, the mapcanvas seems to overflow out the page and the the entire page could scroll down the page by the amount of the navbar.

How would i go about fixing that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe try adding `navbar-fixed-top` to your navbar class.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <nav bar stuff......>
</div>
```

If you don't want the navbar to be over the map set the `#mapcanvas` as this (works till IE7 - haven't tried ie6)

```css
html,body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}

#mapcanvas {
    background:red;display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:50px; /* adjust top margin to your header height */
}
```

```html
<div id="mapcanvas">asdf</div>
```

Comment: That blocks some Google Maps control.

Comment: That doesn't seems to work either with gmaps enabled. From what I can see initially, gmaps creates a bunch of stuff and I don't know how they work..

Comment: @ultimatebuster Wouldn't know how it works with gmaps - but check if you are wrapping the whole google map - so no styles from gmap affect the #mapcanvas div - it should work.